# error TS2591: Cannot find name 'module'

Tags: typescript, angular

Получаю такую ошибку при запуске проекта :

```
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:4:15 - error TS2591: 
Cannot find name 'module'. Do you need to install type 
definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node` and 
then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.**
```

*Код компонента :*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 **moduleId: module.id,** // ошибка!!!
 selector: "my-app",
 templateUrl: "app.component.html",
 styleUrls: ["app.component.css"]
 }) export class AppComponent {}
```

`npm i --save-dev @types/node` - это я установил, но мне
непонятно, как сделать это - `node` to the types field in
your tsconfig. То есть, в каком разделе это прописать,
какое свойство и с каким значением?

---

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },

  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Покажите `tsconfig.json`

Comment: {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },

Comment: "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}

Comment: В пост, а не комментарии